How can I replace this bathroom vanity light?
I had to hold my phone above the glass cups and take this pic. I am not sure how to remove. The glass cups cannot be removed as the bulbs seem to hold them down. I may need to use more force, but unscrewing / twisting+pulling don't seem to be working. If I have to remove the screw, I can't really get my screwdriver to fit since this was installed too close to the ceiling.


Try unscrewing the ceramic ring.

